# Typescript type predictate for element of tuple

Tags: typescript, filter, types, assertion

I have an array which has a type of `Array<[string, unknown]>`. I want to filter this array by whether the second element of the tuple of a `.type` property.

I can't work out a type predictate that will properly give the correct type of output array after the filter is applied.

I have tried this:

- Predictate function:

```
const isSchemaProp = (entry: unknown): entry is [string, { type: string }] => {
  const [, value] = entry as [string, { type: sting }];
  return value.type !== undefined;
};
```

- However

```
const newArr = arr.filter(entry => isSchemaProp(entry)) // Second element of each element is still unknown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter`'s callback function argument must be the function with the type predicate in order for `filter`'s return type to be altered. Calling the type assertion from inside the callback isn't enough.

```
const newArr = arr.filter(
  (entry): entry is [string, { type: string }] => {
    return isSchemaProp(entry)
  }
)
```

Or, since the type predicate has this feature is well, you can just pass that in directly:

```
const newArr = arr.filter(isSchemaProp)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=4.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAysAFgUwLYEMAKAnEABxgF4YAKNMKPATwC4YBXMAazBAHcwBKRqmrXgQYAbWh44YAOYAaGAG8YUWoTSMJU6TAC+AXVIA+RQCgYMUJFij5ANywAbJmgNkBdGFhHiaW+UpU1DV8ZXT0AbjMYPDQoJjwwGHsnNAA6QLQYAEISMhYAEzQAMyk0fMidSJNLaE88PEYfSRl5FnYuMD1RVzE9avBasDROAEF60jq8VJKHKDQ8cgRkdGx8Ih4YAHpNixB6tGBYDMbNFsVlVXUYU+19bpMgA)